# Is there a plugin/extension to disable CSS on certain sites and not others when browsing?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, plugins, css

Is there a plugin/extension to disable CSS on certain sites and not others when browsing?
Sort of like the ability featured in web dev toolbar plugins, but selective and automatic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone - I ended up using the personalized web extension for Chrome (http://goo.gl/XivM) to accomplish this. It can block images/CSS for an entire domain every time you visit it.

Answer (score 4):

This [Firefox Accessibility Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5809) allows you to turn off CSS when needed, and it also allows users to utilize their own stylesheet if needed.

I haven't found one for Opera, but you can also try the "Remove CSS" bookmarklet described [here](http://dorward.me.uk/software/disablecss/). In Opera, you could also switch from author mode to user mode, which deactivates the CSS. A button is available for that.

**EDIT**: I tested the "Remove CSS" bookmarklet on Opera v10.53. It appears you may need to turn on the "Personal Bar" within Opera to install it as a bookmarklet. It removes CSS on websites only; reloading the webpage restores the CSS formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You guys just need to use Stylish (for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)). Then get Stylish-Custom (you can find it in the userstyles forum in a thread).

One of the extra features allows what you guys want. You can set rules where any particular CSS file will turn on/off depending on what site you are currently viewing.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox (Win and Mac)

```
Via the menu toolbar, choose: "View" > "Page Style" > "No Style"
Via the Web Developer Toolbar, choose: "CSS" > "Disable Styles" > "All Styles"
If the Web Dev Toolbar is installed, people can use this keyboard shortcuts:
    Command + Shift + S (Mac)
    Control + Shift + S (Win)
```

Safari (Mac)

```
Via the menu toolbar, choose "Develop" > "Disable Styles"
```

Opera (Win)

```
Via the menu, choose "Page" > "Style" > "User Mode"
```

Chrome (Win)

```
Via the gear icon, choose the "CSS" tab > "Disable All Styles"
```

Internet Explorer 8

```
Via the menu toolbar, choose "View" > "Style" > "No Style"
```

Internet Explorer 7

```
via the IE Developer Toolbar menu: Disable > All CSS
```

Internet Explorer 6

```
Via the Web Accessibility Toolbar, choose "CSS" > "Disable CSS"
```

Comment: In Firefox, unlike using an extension such as Stylish, however, this will load the CSS version of the website first (even on subsequent loads to the same page).  You also have to manually disable the stylesheet every time, so the CSS version is still loaded & displayed initially.  Also, the OP is looking for a solution to disable CSS on certain sites (automatically), and not all websites.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/).  It'll let you manipulate CSS.

Comment: Not what im looking for - you have to turn this feature manually on and off yourself